# Unable to validate the month and year using jscript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to validate month and year via two dropdowns in asp.net using custom validator. But  it isn't running dynamically

```
<script language="javascript">
    function validateNumber(oSrc, args) {
        var month=document.getElementById('<%=ddlccExpirationMonth.ClientID %>').value;
        var year=document.getElementById('<%=ddlccExpirationYear.ClientID %>').value;
        if ((month<DateTime.Now.Year) || ((year == DateTime.Now.Year && month < DateTime.Now.Month)) 
        { 
            args.IsValid = false; 
        } else { 
            args.IsValid = true; 
        } 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Add that script block to your question so it is easier to read for all of us.

Comment: Where is your custom validator server control markup?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `DateTime.Now`! It's Javascript, not C# there!!!

Use these values:

```
var today = new Date();
--var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (year < yyyy || (year == yyyy && month < mm)) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

And it would be interesting to know why you were trying to do: `month<DateTime.Now.Year`, comparing a month with an year!

Technically an `if` just to set a bool variable is a waste of space!

```
args.IsValid = !(year < yyyy || (year == yyyy && month < mm));
```

Comment: Oh thanks. But I've the C# cod and it's working if ((CardExpiryYear < DateTime.Now.Year) || (CardExpiryYear == DateTime.Now.Year && CardExpiryMonth < DateTime.Now.Month))
            {
                lblMonthYear.Visible = true;
                lblMonthYear.Text += "Sorry! Your card has expired<br/>";
                lblUnSuccessful.Text += "Sorry! Your card has expired<br/>";
                blnValid = false;
            }

Comment: You have your C# code in you cs files. But that is JAVASCRIPT! And as Pluto wrote :-)

Comment: I need validation dynamically before the data is submitted

Comment: Thanks for the month xantos. I didn't notice

Comment: <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorDate" Display="Dynamic" ServerValidationFunction="ValidateNumber"
                                runat="server" ValidateEmptyText="True" ForeColor="Red" OnLoad="ddlccExpirationYear">*</asp:CustomValidator>                                       **                                                                   I'm using this custom validator to call the script but it is throwing an error "ddlccExpirationYear' is a 'field' but is used like a 'method"

Comment: @AxelKartikRaykker Remove the `OnLoad="..."` and put `ClientValidationFunction="validateNumber"`

Comment: Thanks Xantos. But it still isn't updating the user about the expiry date before the form gets loaded.